# Keycloak - Custom Entity Id for SAML Provider?

Tags: saml-2.0, keycloak

I am trying to configure a third party product in our Keycloak as an Identity Provider. Unfortunately, this can not handle the URL included in the export as SAML entityId.

```
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="https://sso-keycloak-dev.app.ose.sbb-aws.net/auth/realms/master">
```

The entityId is not part of the Keycloak configuration and is obtained from the base path and the name of the realm (according to the Keycloak source code).

So, is there any way to override this entityId in Keycloak?

Answer (score 4):

We have the same issue here. For now this is not possible and we need to implement our own custom SamlIdentityProvider for connecting. Maybe we can try to make this configurable in Keycloak and propose a pull request. I'll post something on their mailinglist to check the interest.

Comment: I have the same issue and it appears a custom SamlIdentityProvider is still the way to go. Was the proposal accepted and am I overlooking it?

Comment: @Sparwer I have same issue and cannot use the reaml url as entityID but I have an option to specify SAML 2 xml.  Do you know if there is a way to generate entityID that Keycloak likes or can you point me to source code?

Comment: Since Keycloak 13 it is possible to manually specify the Service Provider Entity ID. See: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#saml-v2-0-identity-providers